# Database Corruption - Disk Image Is Malformed - Unraid - Plex

Tags: sqlite, plex

I am not sure where a question like this really falls as it is from an Unraid Linux server, with a Plex Media Server container, which utilizes SQLite (looking for troubleshooting at the root level). I have posted in both Unraid, and Plex forums with no luck.

My Plex container has been failing time and time again on Unraid resulting in me doing integrity checks, rebuilds, dump, import, and a complete wipe and restart (completely remove old directory and start over). At best I get it up for a few minutes before the container fails again. The errors I am receieving have changed but as of the last situation (complete wipe and reinstall of a new container) I am getting the following error in the output log:

> Error: Unable to set up server:
> sqlite3_statement_backend::loadOne:database disk image is malformed
> (N4soci10soci_errorE)

I decided to copy the database onto my windows machine and poke around the database to get a better understanding of the structure. Upon viewing a table called **media_items** I get the same error.

[image: error]

Clearly one of what I assume to be main tables is corrupt. The question I have then is what if anything can I do to try and fix this or learn about the cause? I would have thought a completely new database would fix my issue, unless it's purely coincidence two back to back databases became corrupted before I could even touch them, with no connection. Could it be one of my media files? Could it be Unraid? Could it be my hard drive?

For context, if unfamiliar with Plex. Once the container is up, it scans my media library and populates it with data such as metadata, posters, watch state, ratings, etc. I get through the full automated build and within 30 minutes it falls apart before I can even customize my library.

Below are references to the bash lines I used in several scenarios throughout troubleshooting. May be useful to someone somewhere.

**Integrity Check:**

```
./Plex\ SQLite "$plexDB" "PRAGMA integrity_check"
```

**Recover From Backup:**

```
./Plex\ SQLite "$plexDB" ".output recover.out" ".recover"
```

**Dump:**

```
./Plex\ SQLite "$plexDB" ".output dump.sql" ".dump"
```

**Import:**

```
./Plex\ SQLite "$plexDB" ".read dump.sql"
```

Comment: As a test, you could try spinning up a Plex docker image and see if it fails in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

After hours, days, and a week of all kinds of troubleshooting. To include resetting the docker image (plus others mentioned in the post), it was suggested in another forum to run a memtest. Put memtest on a bootable USB and I was immediately able to conclude one stick was bad. Upon removing that stick I have zero issues and everything is completely fine... Bizarre.

Comment: Ask a mod to help or give guidance on merging your two accounts into just one account.